# Kentico Changes to Transformations not Staging Despite Staging Task Success

Tags: kentico

We have a Kentico CMS setup with a content-staging instance and a production instance. Up until now, all work had occurred in the Portal Engine. Recently we version controlled both with Git and GitLab and that meant integrating the differences between the code bases we'd accumulated over many years that precede my tenure with this project. I tall seemed to go fine.

Since version controlling the instances, any changes we make to Page Type transformations fail to show up in the production instance after staging them over from the content-staging instance. What's more, when staging the change task over in content-staging, the operation reports as successful. The Page Type's version increments and and updates to Page Type fields show up, but any changes we make to transformations associated with the Page Type aren't there and the transformation's version number in production doesn't increment.

Has anyone ever experienced this before? It would be one thing if the staging tasks were failing, but they always register as successful in the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if you have development mode turned on and the virtual objects (transformations) checked out in the file system.  You need to check these virtual objects back into the database.

If this is not your case, it could very well be there is some unexpected caching or an error which is not being logged.  For this case, check the IIS logs and see if anything shows up there.

Comment: Holy smokes. It would have taken me a while to figure that out. Thanks a lot!